# Get intersect values in a array from Multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

I have this array

```
$data = json_decode('[
        [
            ["Monaco Chain"],
            ["Monaco Diamond Cut","Monaco Plain","Monaco Swarovski"],
            ["11.50 mm","13.50 mm","15.50 mm","17.50 mm","6.50 mm","8.00 mm","9.50 mm"],
        ["18.00","20.00","22.00","24.00","26.00","28.00","30.00","7.00","7.50","7.75","8.00","8.25","8.50","9.00","7.25","8.75","9.50","16.00","9.25"],
            ["ROSE","WHITE","YELLOW"],
            ["10","14","18","21"],
            ["New","Long"],
            ["No","Yes","N/A"],
            ["No","Yes","N/A"]
        ],
        [
            ["Monaco Chain"],
            ["Monaco Diamond Cut","Monaco Plain"],
            ["6.50 mm"],
            ["16.00","18.00","20.00","22.00","24.00","26.00","28.00","30.00","7.50","8.00","9.00"],
            ["ROSE","WHITE","YELLOW"],
            ["10","14","18","21"],
            ["New"],
            ["No","Yes","N/A"],
            ["No","Yes","N/A"]
        ],[
            ["Monaco Chain"],
            ["Monaco Diamond Cut","Monaco Swarovski"],
            ["11.50 mm","13.50 mm","15.50 mm","17.50 mm","6.50 mm","8.00 mm","9.50 mm"],
            ["18.00","20.00","22.00","24.00","26.00","28.00","30.00","7.00","7.50","7.75","8.00","8.25","8.50","9.00","7.25","8.75","9.50","16.00","9.25"],
            ["ROSE","WHITE","YELLOW"],
            ["10","14","18","21"],
            ["New","Long"],
            ["No"],
            ["No","Yes"]
        ]
    ]
    ', true);
```

The subarrays in the main array can be increase, for now there are 3 sub arrays.

How can I get just intersect values as array from the main array.

For example, "Monaco Swarovski", "Long" value should not be on intersect array, because: these values are not exist in all sub arrays.

The output array (intersect) structure must like a sub array on main array format.

For this main array, the output should be this:

```
$data = json_decode('
    [
        [
            ["Monaco Chain"],
            ["Monaco Diamond Cut"],
            ["6.50 mm"],
            ["18.00","20.00","22.00","24.00","26.00","28.00","30.00","7.50","8.00","9.00"],
            ["ROSE","WHITE","YELLOW"],
            ["10","14","18","21"],
            ["New"],
            ["No"],
            ["No","Yes"]
        ]
    ]', true);
```

So, just intersect values in same sub array structure.

I tried so many methods on stackoverflow, but some of them were only working for two sub arrays, some of them did not give exactly the right intersection.

I think we need to use intersect functions correctly for the solution.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Definition of a developer: Will take advise and instruction from other peoples code BUT is prepeared to eventually WRITE something themselves to tailor that other code to do exactly what they want it to do.

Comment: I just need little help, please understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gathering the corresponding sub-sub-arrays for all sub-arrays in a temporary array, and using the spread operator to feed that to array_intersect, you could do it like this:

```
$subArrayCount = count($data);
$subSubArrayCount = count($data[0]);
$result = [];

for($i=0; $i<$subSubArrayCount; ++$i) {
  $temp = [];
  for($j=0; $j<$subArrayCount; ++$j) {
    $temp[] = $data[$j][$i];
  }
  $result[] = array_intersect(...$temp);
}
var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/0OcbN

Comment: (Your example result appears to be wrong, `["18.00","20.00","22.00","24.00","26.00","28.00","30.00","7.50","8.00","9.00"]` is missing the value `16.00` which is also contained in all of those 4th sub-sub-arrays.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @misorude, Your code is awesome but, when I use your code: some subarrays converted to object, can we get all subarrays as array ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; the image link doesn’t seem to work.